# JavaScript/Jquery Collision detection for popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I'm writing a web app that supposed to run on both iPad and Desktop Browser.

I have a filters section with popup coming from the side (the popup is absolutely positioned relative to the filter `<li>` tag):

[image]

It all looks nice and dandy on desktop, but on an Ipad in landscape mode, the bottom of the popup is cut since it goes beyond the viewport.

I tried solving it using [queryUI position](http://jqueryui.com/position/):

```
$('.capbIpadPopupAutoComplete').position({
    "my": "left center" ,      //  Horizontal then vertical, missing values default to center
    "at": "left top",     //  Horizontal then vertical, missing values default to center
    "of": $(this).closest('li'),     //  Element to position against 
    // "offset": "20 30" ,      //  Pixel values for offset, Horizontal then vertical, negative values OK
    "collision": "fit flip" //  What to do in case of 
});
```

but that only works if the popup collides with the left side of the screen and not the bottom.

I also need to make sure the triangle moves accordingly as it should always point to the correct filter.

Am I using JqueryUI position wrong? is there a better solution?

[Here is a very simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3rAb/)

Comment: Your fiddle is too simplified - it's not using JQUI, or any javascript at all. JQUI is what's supposed to handle the flipping.

Comment: Uh, are you going to respond?

Comment: @user1618143 -  Sorry, i was on vacation. I will try it tomorrow and see if it helps

Comment: ...So did it work? The bounty's about to expire, you know.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it looks like the biggest problem is that `"flip fit"` isn't actually a valid value for `collision`. (I think it's being treated as `"flip"`.) You're probably looking for `"flipfit"` (no space), or maybe just `"fit"`. You should also make sure to align the *right* side of the popup with the left side of the `li` - aligning the left with the left makes them overlap, and then it flipped because there wasn't enough room. I tweaked your code and got it working better (but still not perfectly; you'll have to tweak it).

```
$('.capbIpadPopupAutoComplete').position({
    "my": "right top" ,      //  Horizontal then vertical, missing values default to center
    "at": "left top",     //  Horizontal then vertical, missing values default to center
    "of": $('.capbStrategicPlan'),     //  Element to position against 
    // "offset": "20 30" ,      //  Pixel values for offset, Horizontal then vertical, negative values OK
    "collision": "fit" //  What to do in case of 
});
```

`$(this)` didn't seem to be working in the `of` argument, so I replaced it.

You also need to not set the `right` value of the popup, since `.position` sets the `left`, and setting both squeezes the popup.

As for the arrow, why don't you just position them separately? If the popup has to move in a little, it'll overlap the arrow some, but that'll just make the arrow look smaller.

Comment: It didn't work, not sure why, i tried all kinds of variations but nothing helped. Eventually i implemented the collision detection my self...

Comment: Did you pop up the popup and then resize the window? That would explain why it's not working for you; `position` only looks at the size of the window when it first runs; it doesn't keep watching and adjusting itself.

Comment: I know, i opened it on Ipad where it collides the first time it opens